# What happens when an object is assigned to a value in c++

Tags: c++, oop

Check the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class example
{
    public:
    int number;

    example()
    {
        cout<<"1";
        number = 1;
    }

    example(int value)
    {
        cout<<"2";
        number = value;
    }

    int getNumber()
    {
        cout<<"3";
        return number;
    }
};

int main()
{
    example e;
    e = 10;
    cout<<e.getNumber();
    return 0;
}
```

What is the output of the above code. Also, I want to know what happens when an object is directly assigned to a value. How will the compiler interpret it?

Comment: *"What is the output of the above code"* - Tried running it?

Comment: Yes the output is: 12310
But I want to know what happens when "e = 10" is encountered.

Comment: Learning to use C++ is not done via asking for tutoring on SO. [Pick a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and follow that.

Comment: `e = 10;` causes `example(int value)` implicit constructor to be invoked constructing a temporary instance of `example` and assigning it to `e` using compiler-generated assignment operator. A good practice to avoid such behavior is marking all constructors beside default and copy/move as `explicit`.

Comment: Use a debugger. @AllenRichards

Comment: Terminology check: you assign a value to an object, not an object to a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you typed

```
example e;
```

So first constructor called and `1` printed

```
example()
{
    cout<<"1";
    number = 1;
}
```

output :

```
1
```

then you typed :
`e=10` its equal to `e = example(10);` so another constructor called :

```
example(int value) /// beacause you used example(10)
{
    cout<<"2";
    number = value;
}
```

so your output is :

```
12
```

and `number` is `2` 
Finally in :

```
cout<<e.getNumber();


3 is couted but in the other hand value is `10`
```

because `number = value` your `number` is `10`
 So in Finally your output is :

```
12310
```

> thanx for @StoryTeller  for editting explaintions